# Is POP3 thread safe?

Tags: python, email, pop3

I use `poplib` to retrieve new messages from my gmail.

I do it in the following way:

```py
server = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
# ... login with credentials

#get info about new mails (1)
emails, total_bytes = server.stat()

for i in range(emails):
    # get new mail (2)
    response = server.retr(i+1)
```

I was wondering what may happen if between `(1)` and `(2)` gmail mailbox receive new emails?

I tried by myself and `(2)` works only with messages that were actual at the moment of retrieving information about them `(1)` and no new messages were fetched from the server.

Is this guaranteed by POP3 protocol or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, POP3 locks the mailbox.

From RFC 1939:

> Once the POP3 server has determined ... that the client should be given access to the
> appropriate maildrop, the POP3 server then acquires an exclusive-
> access lock on the maildrop, as necessary to prevent messages from
> being modified or removed before the session enters the UPDATE state.